# Appcelerator error tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=400

Tags: node.js, npm, appcelerator

Suddenly this error showing up whenever I try to run my android app in appcelerator. Any idea what caused this?

```
[ERROR] :  tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=400
[ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 1
TRACE  | titanium exited with exit code 100
ERROR  | Error: ti run exited with error code 100
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Admin\.appcelerator\install\5.0.3\package\node_modules\appc-cli-titanium\plugins\run.js:89:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by deleting C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm folder and restart appcelerator two times.